# Is there a Stack Exchange site to talk about the state/health of walls and architecture?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask some question related to the health and maintenance of walls, houses, etc., but I am not sure where to ask...is there already a place where I could ask or does it need to be made (if not already existing)?

Even if it's not exactly the place to ask, at least closest in terms of on topic if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s the [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site which may be your best fit. Take a look at the [walls tag](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/walls) and you’ll probably find questions similar to the ones you want to ask.